# Snapping many vertices from line or polygon layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I have several lines(streets) and polygons(plot layout of areas) that the shared points (lines: road intersections, polygons shared plot corner) are not connected.

Is it possible to auto snap all the points using QGIS and which tool can i use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new Geometry Snapper plugin with QGIS 2.12.0. From the change log of 2.12.0:

http://changelog.qgis.org/qgis/version/2.12.0/

*Geometry Checker and **Geometry Snapper** plugins
Two new plugins (which you need to manually enable in the plugin manager) are available for validating and correcting geometries. The Geometry Checker plugin (pictured right) will check and correct your vector dataset for a number of different types of systematic errors and attempt to resolve them for you. After resolving an error, the error list is automatically updated so that if, for example, fixing one error also resolves other errors, all the errors are removed from the issue list.
**With the Geometry Snapper tool you can align the edges and vertices of one vector layer to the edges and vertices of a second layer using a user defined tolerance.***