# Filling gaps automatically in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image]

Can I close the gap between these two polygons automatically, without using editing tools?

Is there a plug in to do this?

Comment: As mentioned in this post: [Snapping many vertices from line or polygon layer in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167865/snapping-many-vertices-from-line-or-polygon-layer-in-qgis), it seems that currently, the only available plugin is the **Geometry Snapper** but it requires a _reference_ layer as well as your input layer and matches the vertices of one layer to another.

Comment: You can use the merge option from the advanced digitizing tools. Just select both polygons and than press the merge/combine button. It will ask you what information the table should get.